# Wordpress Pods plugin - Template Content field doesn't show up

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, podscms, genesis

I enabled Templates from under Components. I clicked on "Ad New", put in a name, however the template field is empty. There isn't any place to type code.

http://prntscr.com/5e2414

As seen on the screenshot the template field is empty. Would anybody know how to enable it or what went wrong?

(I'm using the Genesis theme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue, which is a caused by xcache on certain servers, is fixed in Pods 2.5-beta. You can get it from our GitHub or from http://pods.io/latest

Answer (score 1):

**I suggest you better ask this question to Plugin Support on WordPress.org at https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/pods**